# MySQL Search A Comma Delimited String

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have a table with a column that contains a list of tags/labels in a comma delimited list.  For example: `pending,review,accounting`.

I want to do a SELECT by searching for given tags.  If I do:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_records WHERE TAGS LIKE %review%`

This works just fine.  However, If I do something like:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_records WHERE TAGS LIKE %pending,accounting%`

This yields no results.  Is there a way to accomplish this without having to do a million different LIKE statements?  Essentially if any of the tags specified in the LIKE query matches a tag in the column, I'd like to return the record.

Thank you!

Comment: The FIND_IN_SET functionality doesn't accomplish what I asked.  The search values could be a comma-delimited list as well `pending,accounting` and I need to find either of those values in a column that could, as an example, have `accounting,pending,flagged`

Comment: if we split the search into a separate tags, we can search for each ...`WHERE FIND_IN_SET('pending',tags) OR FIND_IN_SET('accounting',tags)`. Without FIND_IN_SET, we could do something like `WHERE CONCAT(',',tags,',') LIKE '%,pending,%' OR CONCAT(',',tags,',') LIKE '%,accounting,%'`